# Unestablished connection and content manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

The following function allows to use the with-statment and the a pop connection. But if the connection is not established, the quit() in finally will raise an exception. How can this be fixed?

```
@contextmanager
def pop_connect(server, user, password, timeout, use_SSL=False):
    try:
        pop = poplib.POP3_SSL if use_SSL else poplib.POP3
        pop_conn = pop(server, timeout=timeout)
        pop_conn.pass_(password)
        yield pop_conn
    except poplib.error_proto as pop_error:
        print('Authentication for receiving emails failed:{}'.format(pop_error))
    except OSError as os_error:
        print('Name resolution or connection failed:{}'.format(os_error))
    finally:
            pop_conn.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can put your `pop_conn.quit()` in a `try:` with `pass` as corresponding `except` action:

```
finally:
    try:
        pop_conn.quit()
    except <WhaterverException>:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to rethrow the exceptions in the handlers. The contextmanager than does not except the yield:

```
@contextmanager
def pop_connect(server, user, password, timeout, use_SSL=False):
    try:
        pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL(server,timeout=timeout) if use_SSL else poplib.POP3_SSL(server,timeout=timeout)
        pop_conn.user(user)
        pop_conn.pass_(password)
        yield pop_conn
    except poplib.error_proto as pop_error:
        print('Receiving mail failed:{}'.format(pop_error))
        raise
    except OSError as os_error:
        print('Name resolution or connection failed:{}'.format(os_error))
        raise
    finally:
        try:
            pop_conn.quit()
        except UnboundLocalError:
            pass
```